# Obtain the next times (in VARCHAR) from the DB in PHP, according to time now

Tags: php, mysql, time

i have this mysql table with the timetables the train with **php**,

```
Type (INT) | time_start | time_stop
  1        |  09:31:00  | 09:34:00
  1        |  09:43:00  | 09:47:00
  1        |  09:55:00  | 09:58:00
  1        |  10:07:00  | 10:10:00
  1        |  10:33:00  | 10:36:00
  1        |  10:45:00  | 10:47:00
  1        |  10:57:00  | 11:00:00
  1        |  11:12:00  | 11:15:00
  1        |  11:35:00  | 11:38:00
```

(and it goes on..)

- "type" is the timetable type, cus it changes in the winter, summer, etc.
- "type" is INT, and "time_start" and "time_stop" are VARCHAR(8)

I would like to know the most efective way to get the 6 next "train times", acording to the time now.
Imagine, it's now 09:33:10, what I want to obtain is this ones:

```
  1        |  09:43:00  | 09:47:00
  1        |  09:55:00  | 09:58:00
  1        |  10:07:00  | 10:10:00
  1        |  10:33:00  | 10:36:00
  1        |  10:45:00  | 10:47:00
  1        |  10:57:00  | 11:00:00
```

If theres any change I should do in the mysql table, I'm open to your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply could change the VARCHAR type to TIME type, and do a SQL request like
 `SELECT * FROM <yourtable> WHERE time_start > NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is this:

```
select *
from timetables tt
where tt.time_start > current time
order by tt.time_start
limit 6
```

There are two challenges with this.  The first is midnight.  Presumably, if the time is late in the evening, then you want trains in the early morning as well.  The second is converting the times to the right format.

```
select *
from timetable tt
order by (t.time_start > time(now()) desc,
         tt.time_start
limit 6
```

The trick is to move the `where` condition into the `ordering clause`.  In effect, this starts the ordering at the current time *and* continues it after midnight.  This allows you to select the six with wrapping.

The `time()` function should be doing the necessary conversion for the comparison.

Comment: I changed the type to time, and it worked, so i didn't even try this, but thanks any way!

Comment: @MiguelSantos . . . It works even when the next trains are the next day?

Answer (score 0):

The query will be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE time_start >=time(now()) 
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your searched time to an int:

```
$char_time = '09:33:10';
$int_time = (int) str_replace(':','', $char_time);
```

and then construct your sql like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, CAST(REPLACE(time_start, ',', '') AS INT) as mytime 
        FROM yourtable WHERE  mytime > $int_time
        ORDER BY mytime LIMIT 6";
```

Basically what we do above is just casting your `varchar` time field to an `int` type, and using that for comparing, this is a good solution if you can't change your database fields to be of `TIME` type.